# AXIS2C WSDL2C codegen

Tags: wso2

I feel helpless especially without proper documentation for WSDL2C codegen tool. Here is the question with little background:

I was able to download the WSO2-WSF-C-SRC (C source) and able to compile and get the SOAP server running. Also created a wsdl file and generated server skeleton code using WSDL2C codegen tool. The codegen code is way bigger than the code that appears in the Samples provided in the download. Unfortunately, there isn't much literature for the code generated by the WSDL2C tool. Can someone help as to how the start my business logic coding? How to set some default values to all the output parameters? I was able to figure out the location to start. I wish there is a sample code somewhere with the business logic code as well. Can someone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I cracked the code. Obviously, one has to go through the code to understand the basic structure, which I did, finally.

Best Wishes.